# Javascript ID Extracted From String Not Working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

Here's the situation:

```
function STP() { var LOC = window.location.href;
                 var CSV = LOC.substring(LOC.indexOf(',')+1);
                 var ARR = CSV.split(',');
                 var STR = ARR[ARR.length -1 ];
                 var POS = window.document.getElementById(STR).offsetTop;
                 alert( STR ); };
```

Explained:

1. When the page loads, the onload calls the script.
2. The script gets the location.href and Extracts the element ID by
   creating an array and referencing the last one.
3. So far so good.
4. I then use that to reference an element ID to get its position.
5. But it doesn't work.
6. The STR alert indicates the proper value when it's placed above POS, not below. The script doesn't work at all below that point when the STR var reference is used.
7. However if I do a direct reference to the ID ('A01') no problem.

Why does one work and not the other when both values are identical? I've tried other ways like using a hash instead of a comma and can extract the value that with .location.hash, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: If you share an example of the value assigned to `LOC` it may be easier to understand what and where the problem might be.

Comment: You might want to step through the code using the F12 debugger. It seems like `window.document.getElementById(STR)` should be failing, but you're saying it works with `A01`. I suspect there might be whitespaces around the text, but it's hard to know without a [mcve].

Comment: What pertinent data could there be elsewhere if the value returned by STR correct? But here you go:

Comment: The whole gory string. A01 is cleanly removed with no whitespace:file:///M:/Transfers/Main%20Desktop/Export/USI/2018/Catalog/CAT-Compilations-01a.htm?1525149288810, A01

Comment: Yes this is all between local files. Everything else works fine, so I have all those settings right. Besides that, the ID is on the same page as is loaded.

Comment: OK I git the space out. I'll muck with it some more now to see if that's the final solution and report back later. Thanks!

Comment: OK fantastic! You guessed it right off the top. Now to see if there's a way to give you an up-vote or something :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do

```
LOC.substring(LOC.indexOf(',') + 1);
```

you're putting *everything* after the `,` into the `CSV` variable. But there is a space between the comma and the `'A01'`. So, the interpreter reduces it to:

```
var POS = window.document.getElementById(' A01').offsetTop;
```

But your ID is `'A01'`, not `' A01'`, so the selector fails.

```js
function STP() {
  var LOC = 'file:///M:/Transfers/Main%20Desktop/Export/USI/2018/Catalog/CAT-Compilations-01a.htm?1525149288810, A01';
  var CSV = LOC.substring(LOC.indexOf(',') + 1);
  var ARR = CSV.split(',');
  var STR = ARR[ARR.length - 1];
  console.log(`'${STR}'`);
}
STP();
```

To solve this, you can increase the index by one:

```
LOC.substring(LOC.indexOf(',') + 2);
```

But it would probably be better not to put spaces in URLs when not necessary - if possible, send the user to `'file:///M:/Transfers/Main%20Desktop/Export/USI/2018/Catalog/CAT-Compilations-01a.htm?1525149288810,A01'` instead.